# Subir XLS y guardar en base de datos MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Tengo un archivo excel necesito guardar toda su informacion en una base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con c# mvc y javascript.

Y para capturar el archivo tengo:

```
<input type="file" id="Upload">
```

Necesito su apoyo.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Será necesario que agregues todo el código relacionado con tu problema, de otra forma, será imposible poder ayudarte

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar de esta manera para poder leer los datos del excel, se llena la  lista, esta lista puedes recorrerla y guardar la información del excel, con tu metodo que tengaas para guadar la información este es el codigo

```
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
        String file = "D:\\xampp\\xampp\\htdocs\\sln-ats\\files\\ATS_SLNKEY_20121204.xls";
 OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file +
            ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"");
 con.Open();
 DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter dadp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", con);
        dadp.TableMappings.Add("tbl", "Table");
        dadp.Fill(dset);
        DataTable table = dset.Tables[0];

for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(table.Rows[i][0] + "\t" + table.Rows[i][1] + "\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
}
}
```